# How to use a url in JSON file which is declared in .env file?

Tags: reactjs, json, url, environment-variables, development-environment

I have created a react app in which I have created a .env file and in this I have declared a URL which I have to use globally in my appplication.

**.env file:-**

```
NODE_ENV=development
REACT_APP_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8082"
```

Now I have used this URL in this way where I want to use it.

```
window.location.href = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}`;
```

In the same way I have to use this URL in some JSON files, but there I am unable to use this URL in the following way which I declared above.

So how this URL can be used in a JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to use variables inside a JSON file. But you can use placeholders and then replace them with the value you want.

for example:

```json
{
  apiURL: "$(API_END_POINT)"
}
```

and then inside React you can load the data and replace the variables with the ones you wanted

```js
import jsonFile from "./jsonfile.json"

const Component = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
    JSON.strigify(jsonFile).replace("$(API_END_POINT)", 
    proces.env.REACT_APP_API_URL)
   },[]}
   
   /*
    ...Rest of the code
   */
}
```

Comment: Hi Samyar, This approach is not working in my case.
Anything else we can do?